# Simple increment/decrement counter

Tags: powershell, counter, increment, decrement

I would like to make a simple counter in PowerShell. It must prompt the user whether they'd like a higher or lower number.

The starting number must be 0, and it can't be lower than zero or higher than 10. If the user wants a higher number, it must increment the number with 1, if lower decrement by 1. Then it must be able to stop at the desired number. With this number I can set a registry value.

I don't know an efficient way to prompt the user. I can use the [Read-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx) cmdlet to ask if they typed "higher" or "lower", but is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

For example,

```
$i = 0

while (($i -gt 0) -or ($i -lt 10)){
    $j = Read-Host "The current number is $i, would you like a higher/lower number, or quit?"

    if ($j -eq "higher") {
        $i++
        Write-Host "The current number is $i"
    } elseif ($j -eq "lower") {
        $i--
        Write-Host "The current number is $i"
    } elseif ($j -eq "quit") {
        Write-Host "Final number is: $i"
        break
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Efficiency is in the hands of the operator. If I'm working in a console (PowerShell) environment, popping up a dialog box as suggested below is *less* efficient because it means I have to take one hand off the keyboard and move it to the mouse (if keyboard shortcuts on the dialog aren't readily apparent). Why not add aliases for "higher" and "lower" like "l" & "h" and/or up/down and/or u/d? Other note: You have a lot of redundancy in your nested if/else statements. Use a `switch` on `$j` to do the increment/decrement and save your output for the end of the loop.

Comment: [Write-Host is evil](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Yes/No Prompt Window to get user input.

```
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
$intAnswer = $a.popup("Do you want to delete these files?", 0, "Delete Files", 4)
If ($intAnswer -eq 6) {
    $a.popup("You answered yes.")
}
else {
    $a.popup("You answered no.")
}
```

If you replace the '3' in the fourth parameter of the popup() function you will get Yes, No, and Cancel buttons in the prompt window.

Reference: *[Provide a Yes/No Prompt in Windows PowerShell](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1a386b01-b1b8-4ac2-926c-a4986ac94fed)*